# internetexplorer @font-face (caching?)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, refresh, font-face

I used font squirrels font-face generator and put all my fonts and the stylesheet into a folder called _webfonts in my project folder.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'homesteadreg';
    src: url('homestead-regular-webfont.eot'); 
    src: url('homestead-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('homestead-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('homestead-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('homestead-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');

}
```

In my main css i used the following code to import the css

```
@import url("_webfonts/homesteadreg/stylesheet.css");
```

and also defined a rule for the body tag

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
```

and a rule for the h1 tag

```
    h1 {
    font-size: 68px;
    color: #c8c8c8;
    line-height: 58px;
    font-family: homesteadreg, Helvetica, Arial;
    text-align: center;
}
```

In my header i have a logo which is linked to my index.html

```
<div id="header"><a href="index.html" target="_self"><img src="bilder/logo4.png" border=0 alt="alternativer text" width="192" height="40" /></a></div>
```

In firefox everything renders fine as it should

In Internetexplorer 9 i have a strange bug. On first load everything looks fine but when i click on my logo to redirect to my index.html the whole page is rendered with my custom font ( not onyl the h1 tag).
When i click on my logo once more everything is rendered fine again and stays like that even when i click again on my logo.
Seems to be some caching problem.

I hope anyone can help!

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

It might be down to using `@import` in your main css to include your font.  This method has pretty poor performance.

Have you tried linking to your font-face css from the head of your document instead?